# Is the optimizing compiler allowed to omit a function call indirectly used in a short-circuit?

Tags: c++, c

The C and C++ languages evaluate `||` and `&&` in left-to-right order, and must "short-circuit" the right-hand side if the left-hand side establishes the truth value of the entire expression.

Does either language allow for the generated code to not call `foo()`, if the result of `foo()` is stored in a local variable only used on the right-hand-side of a short-circuit operator?

In the example below, the generated code for `bar()` must emit a call to `foo()`. When compiling `baz()`, could a conformant optimizing compiler remove the invocation of `foo()` since `x` is known at compile-time?

```
int foo(int f);

int bar(int x) {
  int const foo_value = foo(x);
  if (x || foo_value) {
    return 123;
  }
  return 456;
}

int baz(/* assume "void" here for C */) {
  return bar(1); // Can this collapse down to "return 123"?
}
```

Comment: Only if it can prove that this function is pure, which is quite unlikely.

Comment: As long as it doesn't affect the observable behavior of the code, the compiler i pretty much free to do whatever it wants.  In this case, a smart enough compiler could reduce the code to `return 123;`

Comment: Could I ask you to cite the standard? I'm very curious about the specific language-lawyering here :)

Comment: FWIW I see that the latest versions of both GCC (11.1) and Clang (12.0.0) do not apply this optimization at "-O3", which led to my question

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/as_if

Comment: http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.1.2.3

Comment: Even if the standard weren't explicit about this, how would you know if an implementation violated it? The standard doesn't say anything about code generation.

Comment: If the function has side effects (that is it is not pure), then optimizing it away would lead to change of the observable behavior.

Comment: **An actual implementation need not evaluate part of an expression if it can deduce that its value is not used and that no needed side effects are produced (including any caused by calling a function or accessing a volatile object).**

Comment: It can be inlined to `foo(1); return 123;`. `foo(1)` can then be removed if `foo(1)` can be shown to have no side effects.

Comment: Replacing `int foo(int f);` with `int foo(int f) { return f; };` produces some interesting results - live - https://godbolt.org/z/Mxr5f4zc9

Comment: Please focus on posting minimal code.   The function baz() adds nothing to your example.  How could it elide foo() if foo, say, exits the program?  Your boolean isn't even guaranteed to happen.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Compiler optimizations are not permitted to change the observable behavior of the program.

> ```
> int foo(int f);
>
> int bar(int x) {
>   int const foo_value = foo(x);
>   if (x || foo_value) {
>     return 123;
>   }
>   return 456;
> }
>
> int baz(/* assume "void" here for C */) {
>   return bar(1); // Can this collapse down to "return 123"?
> }
> ```

Consider `foo` is (C++):

```
int foo(int f) {
    std::cout << "hello, foo is called. I am an observable side effect";
    return 42;
}
```

Then the compiler cannot optimize the call to `foo` away. The compiler must prove that `foo` has no side effects. If it cannot do that, `bar` and in turn `foo` must be called. Or rather: You cannot tell the difference whether it is called or some optimization is applied, because observable behavior must not change.

Note that certain optimizations are specifically permitted to change observable behavior, for example [copy elision](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision). Though this isnt really in contrast to what I said before, because the C++ standard specifies what is allowed and what not, and optimizations may not deviate from that.

Comment: Edited the original phrasing to use "must" instead, thanks for the correction

Comment: @CharlesNicholson please consider that question making wrong statements is as normal as question conaining broken code, while fixes are for answers. Now that you fixed it my answer is not in-sync anymore. I will fix, it but in general its better not to fix the question according to answers you got, because it can render answers useless

Comment: Compiler optimizations are *usually* not allowed to change observable behavior.   Certain elisions are and not all are required.

Comment: @xaxxon Please elaborate unless you are meaning the undefined behavior.

Comment: copy elision can remove observable behavior which would otherwise be called in the copy constructor.

Comment: @xaxxon in a wider sense this is covered under what is specifed as observable behavior, because the C++ standard specifically allows it. The reason I didn't mention it is that the question is tagged as C and C++. I don't think it is too relevant here

Comment: @xaxxon well ok, I added a note :)

Answer (score 3):

Omitting the function call would not be allowed because it would constitute a change in behavior.

Because `bar` was not declared `static`, it could be called from a different translation unit.  If such code were to call `bar(0)`, then `foo` has to be called to determine the return value of the function.

In addition, because `foo` is not defined in this translation unit, the compiler can't make any assumptions about about the function's side effects and therefore can't optimize it away.

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe This would apply to C++ as well.

Comment: An optimizing linker could conceivably see across translation units and emit an optimal `bar` for constant-argument invocations, accomplishing the optimization even if `bar` is not marked static, right?

Answer (score 2):

Short-circuiting means that the right-hand side operand of the logical operator, and *only* the right-hand side operand, is not evaluated when its result is not needed. It does not mean that any other expression is not evaluated.

The right-hand side operand of the logical operator is `foo_value` rather than `foo()`. These are two very different things.

```
 foo(); foo(); foo();                     // does whatever foo does exactly three times
 foo_value = foo(); foo_value; foo_value; // does whatever foo does exactly once
```

Since `foo()` is not a right-hand side operand of any logical operator, short circuiting has no relevance to its evaluation. The compiler must cause `foo` to be called, or otherwise cause any side effects that `foo` might have.